# Internal Class Constructer... does this work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok sorry guys, I know you guys are gonna tell me I need to search and search, but I have already and I am pretty sure I am correct in assuming this will work the way I want it to, but I figured I would ask here and try to get some professional help on my learning experience since unity answers isn't so great.

Anyways I am trying to start constructing another MMORPG and I am also learning c sharp at the same time. I have a class for Vocation (the job of the player, like mage, knight, ect) that I want to be created during the same time my player class is created, and so I need to use an id to decide which vocation and what property values they inherit.

This is what I have, will this work as I am trying to make it? Or am I doing something horribly wrong...?

**EDIT**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//DONE: abstract: a personage can't be "Vocation", but Mage, Warrior, Archer... 
public abstract class Vocation
{
    //DONE: just a readonly property 
    public int Vid {get; }
    //DONE: just a readonly property
    public string Name { get { return _Name; } }
    protected string _Name = "None";

    //DONE: let's ensure the property to be overriden
    public abstract HitPointsPerLevel { get; }
    public abstract ManaPointsPerLevel { get; }

    //DONE: you don't want this constructor to be public, but protected only   
    //DONE: Assign all the data in one place
    protected Vocation(int vid)
    {
        Vid = vid;
    }
}

//DONE: do not declare derived class as inner one 
internal class Mage : Vocation
{
    sealed public override float HitPointsPerLevel { get { return 12f; } }
    sealed public override string _Name = "Mage";

    //DONE: typo constructor should have been "Mage"
    public Mage() : base(1)
    {
    }
}
```

***HOW DOES IT LOOK NOW GUYS?***

Comment: You're not using the Mage class.

Comment: `internal` means that a class is only accessible from within the same assembly (exe, dll). Without further context I'd say you don't need to bother with that right now. `Mage` is also an inner class, but I don't see a reason why it should be. I assume `Warrior` is a copy-paste mistake, and you meant that to be `Mage`? Finally, why are you passing in a `vid` and assigning it to a read-only property? That won't work.

Comment: If you tried it, you would have seen that `base.Vid = 1;`  produces a compiler error, because `Vid` has no setter. Even `Vid = vid;` fails and wouldn't do anything, because `Vid` always returns `0`. Second, `base.Name = "Mage";` also won't work for the same reason. What you *could* do is have a `protected string _Name = "None"` in `Vocation`, then turn the Name property into `public string Name { get { return _Name } }` and set the field in the `Mage` constructor... which is called `Warrior`? Seriously, let the IDE (Visual Studio) help you with errors like that...

Comment: Yes the warrior part was a mistake. Thank you all so much for explaining so much to me.

Comment: @corak
I think I will defnitely use the way you did with _name for name and some other properties for my vocations class thank you again

Comment: Ok so I took the rewrite and started adding to it, I'm trying the way you were talking about with _Name, just curius if everything looks correct now.

Comment: Again, if you just blindly put this into Visual Studio, it will tell you, that there is a lot wrong with it. You did not specify a return type for `HitPointsPerLevel` or `ManaPointsPerLevel` (previously, you had `float`). The property `Vid` still has no setter. That works with C# 6, but since your tags suggest that you want to use it in Unity and Unity apparently does not even support C# 4 features, you might want to provide a `private set;` there. Then the `Mage` class provides no implementation for `ManaPointsPerLevel` and you can only override `_Name` if you mark it `virtual` in `Vocation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest re-designing the implementation

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//DONE: abstract: a personage can't be "Vocation", but Mage, Warrior, Archer... 
public abstract class Vocation
{
    //DONE: just a readonly property 
    public int Vid {get; }
    //DONE: just a readonly property
    public string Name {get; }

    //DONE: let's ensure the property to be overriden
    public abstract HitPointsPerLevel { get; }

    //DONE: you don't want this constructor to be public, but protected only   
    //DONE: Assign all the data in one place
    protected Vocation(int vid, string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

        Vid = vid;
        Name = name;
    }
}

//DONE: do not declare derived class as inner one 
internal class Mage : Vocation
{
    sealed public override float HitPointsPerLevel { get { return 12f; } }

    //DONE: typo constructor should have been "Mage"
    public Mage() : base(1, "Mage")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not put `HitPointsPerLevel` in the constructor too?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you make the constructor for an abstract class public or protected...

Comment: @HitPointsPerLevel: `HitPointsPerLevel` can well be *complex* (depend on *Mana* in case of `Mage`, *dexterity*, *type of weapon* in case of `Warrior` etc.)

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: you're right, but `protected` is a good indicator that the constrictor has been designed to use in derived classes only

Comment: As shown in this answer, internal as no use in Unity since a class is added to the global namespace by default. It only has meaning if you wrap that class within a namespace. Mage is available anywhere in the project.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko is this necessary to put `virtual abstract`? If we abstract the class it is expected that we should implement the method. Maybe a noob question from me :)

Comment: Is declaring a readonly property like `public string Name {get;}` a "new" feature (C# 6)? In older versions it should probably be something like `public string Name {get; private set;}`

Comment: Yes, it is. @Corak Those can only be set from the constructor.

Comment: @Desperado: I'm sorry for typo, no need in `virtual abstract`, `abstract` is enough.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko just OK, I deleted my answer though after seeing this more advance implementation.

Comment: This is a very nice rewrite thank you very much. @DmitryBychenko it defintely will depend on other things.

Answer (score 0):

The code would work, except for the constructor name (`Warrior` instead of `Mage`).

I do wonder though why `Mage` has to be an internal nested class of `Vocation`. What is the use of that?

I can understand why you would make it `internal`: you don't want to let external assemblies create an instance, you can do that though a factory. However, there is no reason to make the class nested. A base class can stand on its own. Just pull the nested class out, use `protected` members on the base class to be able to communicate between the base class and the deriving class.

A small side note: you can use `this` here instead of `base`:

```
public Mage(int vid) : base(vid)
{
    this.Vid = 1;
    this.Name = "Mage";
}
```

Comment: I thought I could use this, instead of base, it was an accident making it internal and nested.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to comment on in addition to the other answers, but they're all in the context of code review. Maybe this is better in codereview.stackexchange.com.

First of all (this is down to style) - I try to avoid variables named like `Vid` - there's nothing wrong with `vocationId` - better to be descriptive enough.

Secondly, and more relevant to the question, I'm not sure your `Mage`/person, semantically speaking, *is* a vocation - so it shouldn't inherit from it. Maybe it's a person who has a vocation but it's not a vocation itself - it probably won't extend the vocation functionality. Which is the sole intent of inheritance.

Are you trying to shoe-horn in the notion of inheritance for practice-sake?

Also, as an aside, in C# 6 you have expression-bodied properties, so you can condense your code a little:

```
public string Name => "None";
```

Although these look like constants to me. This basically needs a big re-design, start with the OOP fundamentals of encapsulation and keep it simple.

Comment: Unity does not support C# 4, 5 or even 6