# Class and object Inheritance

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

**UPDATED**

Ok so I am playing around with classes and inheritance and I am trying to do something I have seen done before in a game whose source code is C++ and I was wondering if someone here could help me to understand how I would do it with C#.

What I want to do is two things:

First When I create an object of a certain class I want to pass an integer to the constructor and that integer to determine what sublcass will be initialized.

like so: Vocation newVoc = new Vocation(1);
and the 1 would choose the first sublcass or subclass with that VocationId.

Second thing, I already have a Player Class that inherits fine from Creature Class, but I want the Player Class itself to contain a Vocation object. So I can set the vocation, and when I do the properties change and the player has different properties... Here is example code to try to go with what I'm saying, hopefully someone understands what I mean.

Ok so I am now getting an error. Cannot implicitly convert type `Mage' to`Vocation'

this is what I got...

Vocation.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public enum VocationType { Mage, Warrior }

public class Vocation
{

}

public static class VocationFactory
{
    public static Vocation CreateVocation(VocationType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case VocationType.Mage:
                {
                    return new Mage();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

public class Mage
{
    public string Name = "Mage";

    public Mage()
    {

    }
}
```

Player.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : Creature 
{
    public uint Level {get; set; }
    public uint Dexterity {get; set; }
    public uint Vitality {get; set; }
    public uint Intelligence {get; set; }
    public uint Strength {get; set; }
    public ulong Experience {get; set;}

    public Player()
    {
        var voc = VocationFactory.CreateVocation(VocationType.Mage);
        Level = 1;
        Health = 500;
        MaxHealth = 100;
        Mana = 50;
        MaxMana = 100;
        Experience = 0;
        Dexterity = 0;
        Vitality = 0;
        Intelligence = 0;
        Strength = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `Creature`-class have a `Vocation`? Or only the `Player`-class has one? For the first point however you may have a look at the factory-pattern.

Comment: No Creature class does not have a Vocation, as it is a base class also used for NPC's and Monsters.

Comment: @Codinablack As per answer marked by you and approach you have adopted shouldn't  `Mage` be inheriting `Vocation`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't create objects from a base class. Use a factory instead, and maybe a enum to define the type.

If you start off with [Dmitry's answer on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38345241/993547), you can create a factory class that instantiates the objects. For example:

```
public enum VocationType { Mage, ... }

public static class VocationFactory
{
    public static Vocation CreateVocation(VocationType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case VocationType.Mage:
                {
                    return new Mage();
                    break;
                }
        }

        throw new Exception($"You did not implement type '{type}'.");
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var voc = VocationFactory.CreateVocation(VocationType.Mage);
```

Comment: That is a brilliant Idea with the enums. However using this method how would I have the player inherit from the class Mage, or w/e vocation it is, if it were to change.

Comment: @Codinablack You can´t inherit two classes, however you can add as many references to any kind of class as you need, in your example you´ll need one `Vocation`-instance your `Player` refers to. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you don't want a `Vocation` to be a subtype of `Player`, but rather something a `Player` **has**. A `Player` may even have more than one vocation. This reflects the code you have shown.

---

This cannot be done, but there are ways around it.

The constructor requires a type to be specified, and you cannot specify an ancestor, you must specify the actual type you want to instantiate. So a `new Vocation(1)` will create just that, a `Vocation` instance, and never a subclass.

A way around this is to use a `case` statement:

```
switch (vocation)
{
    case 1:
        return new Mage();
    case 2:
        return new Sorceror();
}
```

But this is not good design, I wouldn't do that. In C# you have enums, so at least use those:

```
enum VocationType
{
    Mage,
    Sorceror
}

switch (vocation)
{
    case Mage:
        return new Mage();
    case Sorceror:
        return new Sorceror();
}
```

This is still not good. The problem here is that what you are looking for really is a creational pattern, not a programming *trick*.

What you really want is a *factory* that can create any type of player you want.

The better (maybe still not best) way to do that in c# would be a generic that has a factory method to which you pass the actual `Type` you want to instantiate, much like this:

```
public class PlayerFactory
{
    public Player Create<V>()
        where V : Vocation
    {
        Player p;
        p = new Player();
        p.SetVocation<V>();

        return p;
    }
}
```

The `SetVocation<V>()` method whould be:

```
public class Player : Creature
{
    private Vocation ChosenVocation;

    public Player()
    {
    }

    public void SetVocation<V>()
        where V : Vocation
    {
        ChosenVocation = new V();
    }
}
```

You can now create those instances as follows:

```
switch (vocation)
{
    case Mage:
        return PlayerFactory.Create<Mage>();
    case Sorceror:
        return PlayerFactory.Create<Sorceror>()
}
```

Why all this fuss?

You want to remove yourself from codes like `1` or `Vocation.Mage` and so on as soon as possible and to switch to an actual type (that is, implemented code). The method above allows you to extend your code easily by:

- adding a vocation to the `Vocation` enum;
- adding the `case` to the `switch()`;
- implementing the vocation (e.G. the `Sorceror` class).

Answer (score 0):

For the second point simply create a `Player` and a new `Vocation` (based on the answer of Patrick):

```
var player = new Player { Vocation = VocationFactory.CreateVocation(VocationType.Mage) };
```

This assumes you have a property `Vocation` on your `Player`-class:

```
class Player : Create 
{
    public Vocation Vocation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `First` requirement you can have `constructor` with one `parameter` and call the class whichever you feel like in the implementation of the constructor.

```
public class Class1
{
   public Class1(int i)
   {
       // Your implementation logic goes here
   }
}
```

Below is the updated code of yours which I think will fulfill your `Second` requirement.

```
public class Vocation
{
    public Vocation()
    {

    }
    public Vocation(int i)
    {

    }
}

public class Player : Creature
{
    Vocation v;
    public Player(int i)
    {

    }

    public void SetVocation(int value)
    {
        // if you wanna set it to value 
        v = new Vocation(value);
    }
}
```